# Magento Store View Language

Tags: multistore, store-view, language

I'm trying to set up different languages in my shop. I've created a new folder into '/app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/locale/ called it_IT, then I've created a new file called translate.csv and I've placed it in that folder.
So I've created a new store view called "italian" and i set 'it' as code.
Now, when I set 'italian' as language in my store, it not changes. The strange thing is that it seems to change only some strings.
I've already flush the chache.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add different language of your Magento store (store view) you should go to System -> Manage Stores in the backend. Here you can see stores you have. Сlick on Create Store View in the upper right corner of the window and input store view details (name, code) and assign store view to necessary store

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solved.

I had alreay created the Store View. The problem was that I have to save the store view evrey time I change the 'translate.csv'.
I don't know why but now it works fine.
Thank

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted when you are allowed to do so.